# Atlernative function for Pcolor in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to find an alternative function for pcolor(again not pcolormesh) but some other function that doesn't really include plotting but the end result should be similar to what pcolor is giving.

Thank you.

Comment: Your post is missing reproducible code and test data. Moreover, there is no explanation of what exactly (and why) needs to be different.  It is very unclear. Maybe you want to save the plot as an image without showing on screen?  Maybe [Save Plots as an Image File Without Displaying](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/how-to-save-plots-as-an-image-file-without-displaying-in-matplotlib/) helps (although the versions are quite old in that post),

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.